# compare values with JSON_EXTRACT

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I've got a strange issue when I try to compare values with JSON_EXTRACT.

Here is an extract of my column opening_hours in database :

```
{"1": {"end": {"max_hour": "1290", "min_hour": "840"}, "begin": {"max_hour": "720", "min_hour": "420"}}, 
 "2": {"end": {"max_hour": "1290", "min_hour": "840"}, "begin": {"max_hour": "720", "min_hour": "420"}}, 
 "3": {"end": {"max_hour": "1290", "min_hour": "840"}, "begin": {"max_hour": "720", "min_hour": "420"}}, 
 "4": {"end": {"max_hour": "1290", "min_hour": "840"}, "begin": {"max_hour": "720", "min_hour": "420"}}, 
 "5": {"end": {"max_hour": "1290", "min_hour": "840"}, "begin": {"max_hour": "720", "min_hour": "420"}}}
```

When I search if, for example, "720" is between the min_hour and max_hour of each part of the day (begin and end), I've got results :

```
SELECT *
FROM `service_provider`
WHERE ((JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."begin"."min_hour"') <= '720' 
        AND '720' <= JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."begin"."max_hour"')) 
      OR (JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."end"."min_hour"') <= '720' 
          AND '720' <= JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."end"."max_hour"')));
```

====> GOT SOME RESULTS !

But when I do the same thing with "1200", no result found :

```
SELECT *
FROM `service_provider`
WHERE ((JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."begin"."min_hour"') <= '1200' 
         AND '1200' <= JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."begin"."max_hour"')) 
      OR (JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."end"."min_hour"') <= '1200' 
           AND '1200' <= JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."end"."max_hour"')));
```

-----> NO RESULTS.

Yet it is well between "840" and "1290".

I noticed that only numbers before or equal at "720" gave results, so it doesn't take into account the second part of my query (after the OR). Why ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thought I had was, are those  `JSON_EXTRACT` final values returned as integer or string? And from my testing, it's returning string. So, when you do comparison using "<=" on string, it won't behave like numbers. Let's see your first query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `service_provider`
WHERE ((JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."begin"."min_hour"') <= '720' 
        AND '720' <= JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."begin"."max_hour"')) 
      OR (JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."end"."min_hour"') <= '720' 
          AND '720' <= JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."end"."max_hour"')));
```

This return result because you're using `OR` and the first condition of

```
(JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."begin"."min_hour"') <= '720' 
        AND '720' <= JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."begin"."max_hour"')
```

is `true` because of `{"max_hour": "720", "min_hour": "420"}` are both equal or smaller than `720`. Well, more like "7" is bigger than "4" or similar to "7". What if you remove the first condition in `OR` like :

```
SELECT *
FROM `service_provider`
WHERE (JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."end"."min_hour"') <= '720' 
          AND '720' <= JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."end"."max_hour"'));
```

This won't return you anything since in the first comparison, `"end"."min_hour"` returned `840` hence "8" is bigger than "7" AND the second condition `"end"."max_hour"` value of `1290` being recognize as smaller because "1" is smaller than "7".

I think you got the idea. Since this is comparing string, it's always the first character in the value that being compared first.

A quick workaround to your current issue is to turn the `JSON_EXTRACT` value as integer. My suggestion:

```
SELECT *
FROM `service_provider`
WHERE ((JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."begin"."min_hour"')+0 <= 1200
         AND 1200 <= JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."begin"."max_hour"')+0) 
      OR (JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."end"."min_hour"')+0 <= 1200 
           AND 1200 <= JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."end"."max_hour"')+0));
```

Adding `+0` at the end of the `JSON_EXTRACT` value will quickly turn the string to integer and you might as well just remove `'` from `'1200'`.

If you want to look at the values returned from `JSON` extract and use it, you can move all of them into `SELECT` and use `HAVING` to do comparison like :

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."begin"."min_hour"')+0 bmin,
       JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."begin"."max_hour"')+0 bmax,
       JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."end"."min_hour"')+0 emin,
       JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."3"."end"."max_hour"')+0 emax
FROM `service_provider`
HAVING ((bmin <= 1200 and  1200 <= bmax) or (emin <= 1200 and 1200 <= emax))
```

[Here is a fiddle of my tests](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7a7ea05d80920a80c27dea9de271e252)

Comment: here is [datatype comparison](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements002.htm) document which explain what happen when compare string, although this is a oracle document but I think across different DBMS they will have similar rule. Still worthy to take a look.